# Profile Subtab Apps in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, chatter, subtab-apps

Does anybody know how to use [Subtab App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_subtab_def.htm&type=5) in lightning Experience on Chatter Profile ?

Comment: Have you tried going through the official documentation guide?
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_profile_tabs_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Yes, it work only for Classic. I am not getting the same options for LEX.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Wondering if you ever figured this out